# Get length of wav file in samples with python

Tags: python, wav

I am trying to run python code that processes wav files. I want to get the length of a wav file in samples

After research I found this command

```py
import os

b = os.path.getsize('/somepath')
```

But I am not sure if that gives result in terms of samples.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using scipy you can get the length in seconds using `scipy.io`

```py
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

file_path = "/path/to/yourfile.wav"
(source_rate, source_sig) = wav.read(file_path)
duration_seconds = len(source_sig) / float(source_rate)
```

If you are using `pydub` you can simply read the audio segment and get duration.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(file_path)
print(audio.duration_seconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

The length of an audio or wave file is determined by it's framerate.To get the length try this:

```
import wave
import contextlib
audiofile = '/pathto/your.wav' 
with contextlib.closing(wave.open(audiofile,'r')) as f: 
  frames = f.getnframes()
  rate = f.getframerate()
  length = frames / float(rate)    
  print(length)
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.getsize` will get the size of files in bytes.

```
>>> import os
>>> b = os.path.getsize('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\negley.wav')
>>> b
31449644 #This is in bytes, in megabytes it would be 31.45 Megabytes (which is accurate)
```

Want to get the size in megabytes?

```
>>> b = int(os.path.getsize('C:\\Users\\Will\\Desktop\\negley.wav')) / 1024 / 1024
>>> b
29.992717742919922 #Close enough?
```

Or to get the length in seconds, you can use Taufiq's method of:

```
import wave
import contextlib
audiofile = 'C:\\Users\\Will\\Desktop\\negley.wav'
with contextlib.closing(wave.open(audiofile,'r')) as f: 
  frames = f.getnframes()
  rate = f.getframerate()
  length = frames / float(rate)    
  print(length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the scipy library. Try this:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
audiofile = '/path/to/file.wav'
sample_rate_in_s, data = read(audiofile)
print(len(data))
```